# Selection and insert content to a link with :before with class name does not work

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

Why doesn't the following work:

HTML:

```
<aside class="vcard">
     <a href="mailto:info@cepods.com" class"email">info@company.com</a>
     <a href="tel:7865201412" class="tel">436-560-1487</a>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```css
.vcard a.email:before {
  content: "Contact us: ";
}
```

Is it not possible to add content with this method? I've had the issues several times, is the way of selecting not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They is a syntax error in the HTML.. you forgot the `=` after class..

It should be:  `class="email"`

It works now.. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHPh9/)

Comment: Working too long.. you don't see those small details.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero As a side note, you should check the developer tool (F12) you will be able to see these errors.